# Nginx not appending path when using proxy_path

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy for a few backends. It's probably not relevant, but the backends are all hosted within a single Docker network, and the network is being created using `docker-compose`.

The backends all have the same endpoints that need to be exposed, so to reduce duplicate configuration lines I am trying to use `map`.

```
map $http_host $backend {
    host-a.example.com host-a;
    host-b.example.com host-b;
}

server { 
    listen                  443 ssl;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name             _;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    location / {
        # there is no DNS resolution if we set proxy_pass targets dynamically, 
        # use the docker internal DNS server
        resolver 127.0.0.11; 
        proxy_pass "http://$backend:8080/";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

The `resolver` line has been added as Nginx will otherwise give the error: `no resolver defined to resolve *hostname*`

However with this configuration I am finding that requests are being sent to the wrong path, for example if I send a request to `https://host-a.example.com/books` or `https://host-a.example.com/books/123/front-cover.jpg` the page that is returned is always the root of the site (i.e. `https://host-a.example.com/`), it seems that for some reason proxy_pass is not including the path with the request to the backend server.

Is there a way that I can make this work with `map` or do I need to create a separate `server` block for each of the backends that I want to proxy requests to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`proxy_pass` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> When variables are used in proxy_pass
> . . .
> In this case, if URI is specified in the directive, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI.

You should either remove the trailing `/` (the documentation calls this the *optional URI*) :

```
proxy_pass http://$backend:8080;
```

Or provide the full URL of the request (conveniently available as a built-in variable) :

```
proxy_pass http://$backend:8080$request_uri;
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the second option and it seems to be working. For option 1, what is the rule for whether a `/` should be included in the path or not. I have seen a lot of examples on setting up Nginx proxies, some specify the proxy_pass ending in a `/` others do not, same goes for the location, sometimes I see `location /api/` other times `location /api`

Comment: Usually you add a trailing `/` to `proxy_pass` within a prefix `location` because you want Nginx to rewrite part of the URL before passing it upstream (e.g. `location /api/ { proxy_pass http://example.com/; }` will substitute `/api/` with `/`) in which case it is important that the location and proxy_pass values both end with a `/` for correct substitution. However, If the application also uses the URL `http://example.com/api` (without a trailing `/`) - then the `location /api/` will not match.